# It is legal to create a video game featuring "murlocs"?

Tags: copyright, video-games

In the Warcraft universe, "murlocs" are fish-like living creatures that usually have a green or blue skin. It is legal to create a game featuring "murlocs" outside of Warcraft? (The creature may be protected by trademark, but what about copyright?)

Comment: Do you mean the word "murloc", or also importing graphics from the game?

Comment: The creature's appearance and name.

Comment: Had the name been "Morlocks": H.G.Wells died in 1946

Comment: It was always called "murlocs" from the beginning.